# How to make a video with audio and a static image in VirtualDub

Tags: virtualdub

I swear I used to be able to do this easily by opening an image file, selecting an audio source by going to audio > Audio from other file...   and then to Video > Frame Rate > Change So Video and Audio Durations Match. It is producing a file now but does not play music or show the image. I have a new computer and a freshly installed VirtualDub.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide. It is exceedingly frustrating to be unable to do something I once took for granted being able to do without thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Learn the rule of AAB and ABA in the Check_Route function Learn more about the meaning of both the input parameters and the corresponding return results of the functions in SFIS
20°54'13.3"N 106°41'12.4"E